# How can I render HTML file using VB.NET?

Tags: .net, html, vb.net

Is there a namespace to have an `HTML` file rendered?

The intention is to have it rendered in a VBHTML file e.g.:

`@RenderPage("page-name.htm")`

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2012
- ASP.NET MVC 4
- VB.NET

Comment: There's the `WebBrowser`, which is an embedded IE window. You should find it in the IDE's Toolbox. Of course, a quick search (even of the help files, or at least via Google or Bing) would have turned this up for you.

Comment: You seem to be advising how to open the project with a web browser - as it is called "debugging" in Visual Studio 2012 - which is not what I was addressing with the question.

Comment: No. You asked how to render HTML in VB.NET, and I advised you to use the `WebBrowser` control, which embeds an IE control **in your application** and renders HTML. Read what I wrote, and then read the help file. If **rendering** HTML is not what you're asking, edit your question and ask it differently. I said absolutely nothing about "debugging".

Comment: Your written text has not lead me to the assumption of a `control`.

Comment: I said it was in the Toolbox (the panel on the left side of the IDE where you find TextBox, Button, and other **controls**) in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can make that htm file name as page-name.vbhtml and use @RenderPage("page-name.vbhtml"). It works still as you expected. make sure the path is correct. Not sure this is the proper way to do it. But this worked fine for me.